# My calculation function is not returning anything?

Tags: c++

My function is returning 0?

```
int ResizeLockRatio( int width, int height, int desired )
{
    int returnValue = ( height / width ) * desired;
    return returnValue; // returns 0?
}

int lockedRatioHeight = ResizeLockRatio( 1920, 1200, 1440 );
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 int returnValue = ( height / width ) * desired;
```

you are doing integer divide, truncated to 0 sometimes.

You are passing `width = 1920, height = 1200`, so `height/widht =1200/1920` integer divide will truncate to 0 in this case.

**EDIT:** you may try to first do multiplication then do division according to "Caption Obvlious":

```
int returnValue = ( height * desired ) /width ;
```

Comment: AH CRAP yea.. okay thanks that was it! BAHAHHA I am pro mannnn

Comment: can I simply cast my (float)( height / width )

Comment: @JamesT or `(height * desired) / width` if you want to stick with integer math.

Comment: "*can I simply cast my (float)( height / width )*"  **No!**  That divides *first* (still getting 0) and *then* casts your `0` to a `float`.

Comment: Thanks alllll. lol, I swear I have written so much cool stuff and I cannot even do the simplest task. Damn you javascript and php. you have given me awful habbits.